# mate-session warns about not finding a desktop file

Tags: kde, mate, qt

Getting similar warnings in the system logs:

```
Jul 14 09:11:18 precision-7510 mate-session[5184]: WARNING: Unable to find desktop file 'keepassxc.desktop': V složkách hledání nelze najít platný soubor klíče
Jul 14 09:11:18 precision-7510 mate-session[5184]: WARNING: Unable to find desktop file 'mate-keepassxc.desktop': V složkách hledání nelze najít platný soubor klíče
Jul 14 09:11:18 precision-7510 mate-session[5184]: WARNING: Unable to find desktop file 'kdeconnect-sms.desktop': V složkách hledání nelze najít platný soubor klíče
Jul 14 09:11:18 precision-7510 mate-session[5184]: WARNING: Unable to find desktop file 'mate-kdeconnect-sms.desktop': V složkách hledání nelze najít platný soubor klíče
```

Translation from Czech:

“Can’t find a valid key file in the search directories”

```
Jul 14 09:11:18 precision-7510 mate-session[5184]: WARNING: Unable to load desktop file '/opt/ownCloud/ownCloud/bin/owncloud.desktop': Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
```

Translation from Czech:

“Directory or file does not exist”

All these shortcuts link to KDE or maybe Qt-only applications.

Found a [gdm bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/722761) on Launchpad but it’s marked invalid and the OP didn’t get answer for his question how to fix it.

Mentioned this `gdm` bug because similar messages are cited in there.

So I am asking: How do I fix it so that the warnings go away?

Edit:

OS: Ubuntu MATE 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Desktop: MATE 1.24.0

Tags:

- KDE & Qt because only KDE & Qt applications’ desktop shortcuts cause problems
- MATE because the log messages go from `mate-session`

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details (ie. your software stack); the bug you linked looks *invalid* (ie. related to user's config & not `gdm`) but your tagging MATE, KDE & Qt are not explained; with no provided app details, no software stack details so currently it's unclear (the bug you mentioned is for a package no longer used - is your release that old as it was last used in 14.04?)

Comment: Wow, excuse me for the lack for information. Going to fix it.